# How can I observe the changed state of model items in an ObservableList?

Tags: eclipse, data-binding, jface

I have an ObservableList of model items. The model item is enabled for property binding (the setter fires a property changed event). The list is the content provider to a TableViewer which allows cell editing. I also intend to add a way of adding new rows (model items) via the TableViewer so the number of items in the list may vary with time.

So far, so good.

As this is all within an eclipse editor, I would like to know when the model gets changed. I just need one changed event from any changed model item in order to set the editor 'dirty'. I guess I could attach some kind of listener to each individual list item object but I wonder if there is a clever way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I might have a solution. The following class is an inline Text editor. Changes to the model bean (all instances) are picked up using the listener added in `doCreateElementObservable`. My eclipse editor just needs to add its' own change listener to be kept informed.

```
public class InlineEditingSupport extends ObservableValueEditingSupport
{
    private CellEditor cellEditor;
    private String property;
    private DataBindingContext dbc;

    IChangeListener changeListener = new IChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleChange(ChangeEvent event)
        {
            for (ITableEditorChangeListener listener : listenersChange)
            {
                listener.changed();
            }
        }
    };

    public InlineEditingSupport(ColumnViewer viewer, DataBindingContext dbc, String property)
    {
        super(viewer, dbc);
        cellEditor = new TextCellEditor((Composite) viewer.getControl());
                this.property = property;
                this.dbc = dbc;
    }

    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element)
    {
        return cellEditor;
    }

    @Override
    protected IObservableValue doCreateCellEditorObservable(CellEditor cellEditor)
    {
        return SWTObservables.observeText(cellEditor.getControl(), SWT.Modify);
    }

    @Override
    protected IObservableValue doCreateElementObservable(Object element, ViewerCell cell)
    {
        IObservableValue value =  BeansObservables.observeValue(element, property);
        value.addChangeListener(changeListener);  // ADD THIS LINE TO GET CHANGE EVENTS
        return value;
    }

    private List<ITableEditorChangeListener> listenersChange = new ArrayList<ITableEditorChangeListener>();

    public void addChangeListener(ITableEditorChangeListener listener)
    {
        listenersChange.remove(listener);
        listenersChange.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeChangeListener(ITableEditorChangeListener listener)
    {
        listenersChange.remove(listener);
    }
}
```